# MySql query not working across 2 PCs with same software installed

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I have 2 PCs in my room and i am sharing a project across them (see included diagram for details)
When i open the project1 on my desktop, all of my queries containing the WHERE keyword does not work
as expected.In fact they dont't work at all.In the laptop, the combobox is populated , but the same code, does not populate the combobox in my desktop.What's driving my crazy is the fact that the project works as expected when i load it on my laptop.i am biting my keybord here. Why the same code works on my laptop,but doesn't on my desktop??? And why the query works as expected on my destop when i remove the WHERE part of my query??? Any help appreciated.
[PCs set up diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwMws.png)

```
MySqlcnty = new MySqlConnectivity();
string constring = MySqlcnty.ConnectionString;
string query = "SELECT concat(firstname, ' ', lastname, ' ', '(', asma, ')') FROM person where eidikotita = 'ΙΠΤΑΜΕΝΟΣ'";
using (Connection = new MySqlConnection(constring))
{
    using (Cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, Connection))
    {
        Connection.Open();
        using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, Connection))
        {
            DataSet dt = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(dt, "person");
            CreatedByCombobox.ItemsSource = dt.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            CreatedByCombobox.DisplayMemberPath = dt.Tables[0].Columns[0].ToString();
            CreatedByCombobox.SelectedValuePath = dt.Tables[0].Columns[0].ToString();
            //AskisiCombobox.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "they dont't work at all"? Are you getting an error? If so, copy the error details into the question

Comment: Do you have separate DBs with same configurarions in your both computers?

Comment: i am not getting an error.i am using the MysqlDataAdapter obj to populate a combobox.in my laptop the combobox is populated just fine. on my desktop, seems that MysqlDataAdapter does not return anything from the db.

Comment: i have seperated DBs, i exported the DB from my laptop and imported in the desktop.

Comment: @DRapp It was the connection string...it was missing the 'CharSet=utf8;' part. Now it seems to work fine on both my PCs.Thanks man!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is not querying at all on second machine, I would look directly at the connection string. Is the named instance of the MySQL different on machine 1 vs 2? if so, might that be it? I would start by stepping into via debugging to see if the Connection.Open() even works. If not, that's it. If it does, I would do a simple select * from YourTable. If that fails, permissions?

Comment: @AlxGdr, I posted my comment as an answer so you can check it as solved.  This way, future people might know to check connection string too if not otherwise obvious.